# A set of infinite sequences of only 0s and 1s with a metric, their convergence and the topology they induce?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

The entire question is this:

Let $S$ be the set of sequences of 0s and 1s. For $x = \{x_1, x_2, x_3,...\}$ and $y = \{y_1, y_2, y_3, ...\}$ define $$ d(x,y) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{|x_j -yj|}{2^j} $$

Explain why the infinite sum in the definition converges for all $x$ and $y$.

Prove that $d(x,y)$ is a metric.

Let $E$ be the subset of $S$ consisting of all sequences that are eventually 0. Thus, $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3...)$ is  in $E$ if there exists $N \geq 0$ such that $x_n = 0$ for all $n \geq N$. Prove that $E$ is dense in $S$ under the topology induced by $d$.

---

My first instinct with the metric infinite sum convergence is that of course it converges because either x=y and then it's a sum of infinite 0s, converging to 0, or if x $\neq$ y then we can define a subsequence that is a subsequence of the geometric sequence that converges to 1, so it converges to 1.

I also want this to be true because then it induces the discrete topology which is really easy to work in. But I'm not sure if the convergence is true? Because I was also thinking that we could have an x where each $x_i$ = 0 and $y = \{1, 0, 0, 0...\}$. Then this would converge to 1/2.

So how does this thing converge? Am I overthinking it or underthinking it? I'm stronger with topology than analysis but if it's not the discrete topology I'm not sure where to go.

Comment: GOTCHA! It's *not* the discrete topology. Guess what? It's the Cantor set.

Comment: Thank you! Everything is seeming clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Since the series defining $d(x,y)$ has nonnegative terms it is enough to note that it is maiorized by $\sum_{j\geq1} 2^{-j}=1$ whatever $x$ and $y\in S$.

**2.** The function $d$ is obviously symmetric, and $d(x,y)>0$ when $x\ne y$. For the triangle inequality note that $|x_j-z_j|\leq|x_j-y_j|+|y_j-z_j|$ for all $j$.

**3.** Define the *truncation operator* $T_n: \>S\to E$ by
$\bigl(T_n x\bigr)_j:= x_j$ if $j\leq n$ and $\bigl(T_n x\bigr)_j:=0$ if $j>n$. If $x$ is an arbitrary element of $S$ then $T_n x\in E$ for all $n\geq 1$, and $$d(x, T_n x)\leq \sum_{j>n}2^{-j}=2^{-n}\ .$$
It follows that $E$ is dense in $S$. If the sequence $x$ has infinitely many ones then $T_n x\ne x$ for all $n$, hence the convergence $T_n x\to x$ is nontrivial. This shows that the topology  defined by the metric $d$ on $S$ is not discrete.